# Combining multiple columns into one column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have the following dataframe

```
Animal Animal1 Animal2
Cat    
Dog
Fish   
       Moose
       Horse
       Cow
              Snake
              Bird
              Rat
```

I want to be able to get the desired dataframe:

```
Animal 
Cat    
Dog
Fish   
Moose
Horse
Cow
Snake
Bird
Rat
```

Please Advise on how to do so in python! Thanks

Comment: `df.bfill(1).iloc[:,0]`

Comment: Thanks this works!